# Popup works in Chrome not in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, popup

My html form has two buttons that when clicked display two different popup windows.  In Chrome, both the popup windows are displayed correctly.  In Safari, one of them displays correctly but the other one cause a blank page to display momentarily and revert to the original page.

Both these button use the same js function as follows:

```
function Popup(url,w,h,i) {
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        var target=url+'?concertid='+i;
        window.open(target, "", 'top='+top+', left='+left+', width='+w+', height='+h+' status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no scrollbars=no');
    }
```

The html for the button that works correctly is:

```
<input onclick="Popup('http://www.example.com/JoinPopup.html',512,562)" style="color:blue;font-family:verdana; font-size:16px;" type="submit" value="Join or Renew Now">
```

The html for the button that does not work is:

```
<input type="submit"  style="height:25px;width:92px;border:none;background:url(img/buy-tickets-button.png);" id="5" onclick="Popup('http://www.example.com/TicketsPopup.html',512,650,this.id)" value="">
```

The popups themselves are very similar.  The only major difference between them is that the one that does not work in Safari retrieves some information from a mySQL database and puts it into fields on the form before it is displayed.  That's the reason for passing the concertID variable in the URL.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you realised that your syntax is wrong? lYou're missing a `,` in between `toolbar=no scrollbars=no`. Also, W3schools says no whitespaces allowed, so remove the spaces behind the comma's. I'm not saying this will fix everything, but it might actually matter. -  for testing purposes, on the popup, try just printing the concertID from the url?

Comment: Does `concertId=5` show up correctly in the url?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I fixed the missing comma and the whitespace issue but still the same problem.  I changed the php script that loads data into the popup to do a print_r($_GET) and exit. With Chrome, that confirmed that the concertID is successfully passed.  With Safari, the print_r output did not show and the result was the same as before - a blank page for a second than back to the calling page. I also tried this with Firefox and it works correctly.

Comment: OK, figured out what is going on.  The popup is being displayed by Safari but it is behind the calling window!  How can I make sure the popup is the top window. Vert strange because, as mentioned in the original post, the other popup is displayed as the top window.

Comment: Solved. Needed "return false" after the call to my onClick handler.